# Ruby - Count the number of strings in an array that contain either of two characters

Tags: arrays, ruby, include

I have this `array`:

```
@a = ["P1 - D", "P3 - M", "P1 - D", "P1 - M", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - M", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - M", "P2 - M", "P3 - D", "P3 - D", "P - D", "P1 - M", "P - D", "P - D", "Post - D", "S1 - D", "P1 - M"]
```

Every `string` is based on **Page# - Device**. So `P1 - D` is: *Page1 - Desktop* **&** `P3 - M` is: *Page3 - Mobile*

How can find how many of the `string`s inside `array` has **D** or **M**?

Comment: Might be worth putting what the answer is, do you want a total, i.e. 27 or something like `{"D"=>20, "M"=>7}`.

Comment: You need to edit the title to make it consistent with the question. Perhaps, "Count the number of strings in an array that contain either of two characters."

Comment: Sure, Thanks @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.group_by { |e| e[-1] }.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.count }
#=> {"D"=>20, "M"=>7}
```

Steps:

```
groups = a.group_by { |e| e[-1] }
# {
#   "D"=> ["P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P3 - D", "P3 - D", "P - D", "P - D", "P - D", "Post - D", "S1 - D"],
#   "M"=> ["P3 - M", "P1 - M", "P1 - M", "P2 - M", "P2 - M", "P1 - M", "P1 - M"]
# }

group_counts = groups.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.count }
#=> {"D"=>20, "M"=>7}

group_counts['M']
#=> 20
```

## edit

With Ruby 2.4+ you can make use of [Hash#`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (credits go to [Alex Golubenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4057366/alex-golubenko) :)):

```
a.group_by { |e| e[-1] }.transform_values(&:size)
#=> {"D"=>20, "M"=>7}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, When I run this, I get error: `undefined method last` Please take a look at this link: [function on repl.it](https://repl.it/FzZ2/1)

Comment: @user6589814 that is strange... you could use `group_by{ |el| el[-1] }` then

Comment: `a.group_by { |e| e[-1] }.transform_values(&:size)` ;)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko `transform_values`!! Cool, did not use it before

Comment: Isn't `String#last` a Rails method?

Comment: @EricDuminil that's why it is not working for OP, I tested in rails console, thx! Editing

Comment: BTW, it's not very efficient to use `group_by` just to get the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: @EricDuminil I had the version identical to what you showed (using hash `default_proc`) but just did not paste it (it should have been "Now, more efficient way.." part). Well, busy working day..

Comment: No need for `default_proc` AFAICT, since `0` isn't mutable.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @AndreyDeineko Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

```
@a.group_by { |e| e[-1] }.map {|e, a| [e, a.size]}.to_h
=> {"D"=>20, "M"=>7}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@a = ["P1 - D", "P3 - M", "P1 - D", "P1 - M", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - D", "P1 - M", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - D", "P2 - M", "P2 - M", "P3 - D", "P3 - D", "P - D", "P1 - M", "P - D", "P - D", "Post - D", "S1 - D", "P1 - M"]
@a.count { |string| string.match(/D|M/) }
#=> 27
```

Comment: I like this best because it's efficient and reads best. Having `count` up-front tells the reader what you are doing. In Ruby v2.4+ you can use `string.match? /D\M/`, which arguably reads even better. You could of course use `/[DM]/` instead of `/D}M/`. I suggest you delete the first line. Since the OP defined `@a` it's redundant and it makes your answer less visually attractive.

Answer (score 1):

```
@a.select { |word| word.include?('D') || word.include?('M') }.size
# => 27
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the total, you could use :

```
@a.grep(/D|M/).count
#=> 27
```

If you want subtotals, this should be the most efficient method, since it doesn't create any temporary array :

```
@a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |string, count| count[string[-1]] += 1 }
#=> {"D"=>20, "M"=>7}
```